# BeanIO parsing - combination of fixed length and delimitator(new line)

Tags: java, parsing, bean-io

Example of file:

```
FIRSTSECONDTHIRD  
firstsecondthird
12345^$%$#@abcde
```

I have a Pojo like this:

```
class Pojo{
   String firstAttribute;
   String secondAttribute;
   String thirdAttribute;
}
```

bean xml configuration:

```
<stream name="attributes" format="fixedlength"  >


    <record name="myrecord" class="Pojo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" minLength="16" maxLength="16"  >

        <field name="firstAttribute" length="5" trim="true" />
        <field name="secondAttribute" length="6" trim="true"/>
        <field name="thirdAttribute"  length="5" trim="true"/>

    </record>

</stream>
```

My problem:

I need a way to use "\n" delimiter in combination with fixed length.

So I need a result of 3 objects (one from each line)

I tried with

```
        <parser>
            <property name="recordTerminator" value="\n\r" />
        </parser>
```

but i receive:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Record terminator must be a single character

Comment: is it possible that you might use \r\n instead of \n\r?

Comment: Try `&#x0A;` as a record terminator.